# GGplot shows the mean data incorrectly after grouping in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

The data includes: "Date","hour", "day", "week", "weekdays", "Finished_rides" columns. I want to group the data in a way that it gives me plots of mean of Value for each weekday (Monday, Tueasday, etc.) but in a way that the mean is calculated for the certain day. For example in the plot Monday, the mean should be the average for all the Mondays in the dataset.

The data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1482087600, 1482084000, 1482080400, 
1482076800, 1482073200, 1482069600, 1482066000, 1482062400, 1482058800, 
1482055200, 1482051600, 1482048000, 1482044400, 1482040800, 1482037200, 
1482033600, 1482030000, 1482026400, 1482022800, 1482019200, 1482015600, 
1482012000, 1482008400, 1482004800, 1482001200, 1481997600, 1481994000, 
1481990400, 1481986800, 1481983200, 1481979600, 1481976000, 1481972400, 
1481968800, 1481965200, 1481961600, 1481958000, 1481954400, 1481950800, 
1481947200, 1481943600, 1481940000, 1481936400, 1481932800, 1481929200, 
1481925600, 1481922000, 1481918400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), hour = c(23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 
15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L), day = c(18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), week = c(51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51), weekdays = structure(c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
), class = "factor"), Finished_rides = c(12, 28, 16, 15, 36, 
32, 26, 24, 12, 14, 22, 10, 5, 2, 1, 2, 14.7647798742138, 5, 
11, 30, 27, 25, 29, 36, 31, 32, 47, 48, 38, 20, 21, 20, 14, 17, 
9, 6, 13, 6, 8, 4, 5, 3, 10, 26, 37, 41, 59, 47)), row.names = c(NA, 
48L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
df_Hourly_DriverActivity %>%
  group_by(day, hour) %>%
  mutate(avg_hour_rides = mean(Finished_rides)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hour, y=avg_hour_rides)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Hours", y = "Available drivers", 
       title = "Figure x. Finished rides") +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(
  plot.title = element_text(color = "gray15", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
  axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "gray15"),
  axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "gray15")
  ) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text()) +
  facet_wrap(vars(weekdays))
```

However, in the plots after running the above code, I the mean values are not correct, in some places they are even bigger than the maximum of the column, which is 62. How to correct this issue?
See the plot below:

[image]

Comment: I just edited the question's column names, please refresh it once more if it doesn't coincide.

Comment: There's something definitely wrong here. What is `mutate(avg_hour_rides = mean(Finished_rides))`supposed to produce? You're grouping by `day` and `hour` when you have 24 unique hour per day. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @Nizar Yes, it might not be correct. What I am looking for is to average my data for each hour of each day of a week and plot it. For example, for 2pm in Monday plot, it should take all the 2pms in Mondays, average it and plot, for 3 pm in Tuesday, it should take all the 3pms from Tuesdays and average and so on.

Comment: In this case, aren't you looking for something like this? `df_Hourly_DriverActivity %>%
  group_by(weekdays,hour) %>%
  summarise(avg_hour_rides = mean(Finished_rides))` ? This will produce the average for each weekday by each hour.

Comment: @Nizar yes, that's what I need. Many thanks for helping.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question answered in the comments